# Find files, copy to new directory python

Tags: python, file, copy

I would like to:
Write a script that takes a single directory path as command line argument, and then walks all subdirectories of that path looking for files with the extension '.py', copying each one to a temporary directory in your file system (eg /tmp/pyfiles). Your script should check for the existence of the temporary directory, and remove it if it already exists; it should then create a new directory, before beginning to copy files.

I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
import shutil
#import module

rootdir = sys.argv[1]
#take input directory

if os.path.exists('tmp/pyfiles'):
    shutil.rmtree('tmp/pyfiles')

if not os.path.exists('tmp/pyfiles'):
    os.makedirs('tmp/pyfiles')
#check whether directory exists, if it exists remove and remake, if not make

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ['.py']:
            shutil.copy2(f, tmp/pyfiles)  
#find files ending with .py, copy them and place in tmp/pyfiles directory
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seek.py", line 20, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(f, tmp/pyfiles) 
NameError: name 'tmp' is not defined
```

Could anyone help me out?:) Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your code says `shutil.copy2(f, tmp/pyfiles)`, I believe it meant to be

`shutil.copy2(f, 'tmp/pyfiles')`.

Comment: When I add the quotations, I still get an error however way more complicated stating "No such file or directory: 'theo.py'" which is one of the files is should exactly copy.

Comment: The file does exists because it is one of the test files to see whether the script is working. Meanwhile, I found out the following:
The script works for files in the path given in the command line. However, the theo.py file is a file in a directory in this given path. Which obviously should also be copied, but apparently is goes wrong somewhere..? By the way, thank you for help :):)

Comment: it's because `f` contains only the file name.  `shutil.copy2` expects a full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the 
    os.walk()
method you loose track of the file full path. What I would do is to analyze each directory using the
    os.listdir()
method and then copying each file taking into account its absolute path. Something like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for dir in dirs:        
        for f in os.listdir(dir):        
            if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ['.py']:                                                    
                shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, dir, f), "tmp/pyfiles")
```

I hope this helps, maybe there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the root directory exists and walk in to remove everything if not create a new one.

To copy from `dir` to yours you have to check for files in `dir` that filename ends with `.py`, then replace the dir path with root path and create a new file in root dir with the content of matching file.
If we found a directory in `dir` we should create a new one in the root directory.
After that just call the function recursively to copy all content of `dir` to the root directory

```
import os, sys


rootdir = sys.argv[1]
PATH = "/tmp/pyfiles/"

def check(path, _file):
    global rootdir, PATH
    
    for item in os.listdir(path):
       newpath = os.path.join(path, item)
       if os.path.isdir(newpath):
           os.mkdir(os.path.join(PATH, newpath.replace(rootdir, '')))
           check(newpath, _file)
       else:
           if item.endswith(_file):
               source  = open(newpath, 'r')
               print os.path.join(path, newpath.replace(rootdir, ''))
               output = open(os.path.join(PATH, newpath.replace(rootdir, '')), 'w')
               output.write(source.read())
               output.close()
               source.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if os.path.isdir(PATH):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH, topdown=False):
            for name in files:
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
            for name in dirs:
                os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
        os.rmdir(PATH)
        
    os.mkdir(PATH)

    check(rootdir, '.py')
```